# Gecko WebBrowser unable to open a specific link first time after Restart machine

Tags: browser, gecko

I am new in C# . I have developed own webbrowser with Gecko webBrowser control. But I'm unable to open a particular link for first time, and it return alert for timeout. I handled timeout alert messagebox too.
When I have implemented

private void gWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)

I found out that first time page was not properly loaded.
How can i use auto Reload or timer in it?

My code is:

```
 public partial class Embedded_Browser : Form 
{
    public Embedded_Browser()
    {
        string GeminiURL = "NA";
        InitializeComponent();
        Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
        GeckoPreferences.User["dom.max_script_run_time"] = 0; //let js run as long as it needs to; prevents timeout errors
        GeckoPreferences.User["security.warn_viewing_mixed"] = false;
        GeckoPreferences.User["browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete"] = false;
        GeckoPreferences.User["privacy.popups.showBrowserMessage"] = false;
        GeckoPreferences.User["browser.xul.error_pages.enabled"] = false;
        GeckoPreferences.User["browser.cache.memory.enable"] = false;
      
        gWebBrowser.NSSError += new EventHandler<GeckoNSSErrorEventArgs>(gWebBrowser_NSSError); //Bypass SSL certificate issues
        gWebBrowser.NavigationError += new EventHandler<GeckoNavigationErrorEventArgs>(gWebBrowser_NavigationError); //If there are any issues encountered during page loads
        gWebBrowser.Navigated += new EventHandler<GeckoNavigatedEventArgs>(gWebBrowser_Navigated); //React appropriately to URL navigation

        string sUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; pl; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
        Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["general.useragent.override"] = sUserAgent;

        var observerService = Xpcom.GetService<nsIObserverService>("@mozilla.org/observer-service;1");
        observerService.AddObserver(new Observer(), "http-on-modify-request", false);

        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
        {
            RegistryKey MyReg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Jekson\\AppConfig", true);
            GeminiURL = (string)MyReg.GetValue("Browse_URL", "NA");
        }
        else
        {
            RegistryKey MyReg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Jekson\\AppConfig", true);
            GeminiURL = (string)MyReg.GetValue("Browse_URL", "NA");
         }
       

        gWebBrowser.Navigate(GeminiURL);
        textBox1.Text = GeminiURL;
        PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = () => new NoPromptService();
        //  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if(NoPromptService.isPrompt == 1){
            gWebBrowser.Reload();
            gWebBrowser.Navigate(GeminiURL);
            MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
        }
     }
```

Please Help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have used timer control for making Web browser auto refresh for first time.
After 5ms web browser auto refresh once.

My code is:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        gWebBrowser.Navigate("google.com");  //You can pass any url here which you want to load
        if (count == 0)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
        count++;
    }
```